# when i logout using api and i again send a get request to show the user data, it shows "Route [login] not defined."

Tags: laravel, api, authentication, routes

My Issue :- after logout using api post request and i send a get user details request,it shows a message that "Route [login] not defined.".

My Logout Code :-

```
public function logout(Request $request) {

    $request->user()->token()->revoke();

    $json = [
            'success' => true,

            'code' => 200,

            'message' => 'You are Logged out.',

        ];

        return response()->json($json, '200');
}
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiGQz.png): [image]https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiGQz.png

Comment: Have you defined the route with login name?

Comment: Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');

Route::post('register', 'AuthController@register');


Route::group([
    'middleware'=>'auth:api'
],function () {

    Route::get('user', 'AuthController@details');
Route::post('/logout', 'AuthController@logout');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to redirect to a [named route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#named-routes) whose name is `login`, but you have no routes with that name:

```
Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login')->name('login');
```

In `app\Exceptions\Handler.php` try this it helped me previous

You can just override it in laravel. Just make sure to include

```
use Exception;
use Request;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Response;

 protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
        }


        return redirect()->route('auth.login');
    }
```

Method not allowed `405` error it the problem with routes or csrf protection try this

```
Route::get('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
```

Comment: after adding the above command ,
i get another issue that "Declaration of App\Exceptions\Handler::unauthenticated($request, App\Exceptions\AuthenticationException $exception) should be compatible with Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler::unauthenticated($request, Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException $exception)"

Comment: I send you add this line at the top I updated my answer

Comment: i have add the line on the top,
but still iam not getting any out Put.it shows "Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message"

Comment: Did you add @csrf after form logout?

Comment: what is your name of route?

Comment: route :- Route::post('/logout', 'AuthController@logout');

Comment: logout function :- public function logout(Request $request) {
        $request->user()->token()->revoke();
        $json = [
                'success' => true,
                'code' => 200,
                'message' => 'You are Logged out.',
            ];
            return response()->json($json, '200');
    }

Comment: try with get because method not allowed you just would like manually fool routes

Comment: Just try get method in routes instead post

Comment: So now what can i do .............my problem is that ,when i logout the user and fetching the  user details iam not getting it.instead of getting data iam getting an message that "InvalidArgumentException
Route [auth.login] not defined."

Comment: because you don't have auth.login put just login or what are you using?

Comment: when i put login ,it shows "InvalidArgumentException
Route [.login] not defined."

Comment: I say name of your route

Comment: Can you write php artisan route:list

Comment: on your console and see name of your route

Comment: POST     | api/logout                              |                                   | App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@logout
                         | api,auth:api |